# How to read C global variables from swift?

Tags: ios, c, swift

I want to get global variables in C and use them in swift.

This is Csource.c

```
#include "Csource.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define size 5

int buf[size];

void add()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
         buf[i] = buf[i] + 1;
    }
}
```

This is MySwift2-Bridging-Header.h

```
#include "Csource.h"

#define size 5
int buf[size];
void add();
```

and This is ViewController.swift

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    add()
    var a:Int32 = buf[0]// error Type'(Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32)'has no subscript members
}
```

How can i get global variables in C and use them in swift ?

Comment: Make them public in your C file?

Comment: Are there access modifiers in C ? how can i add public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to declare variable extern in `MySwift2-Bridging-Header.h`, but I don't think it will work:

```
#define size 5
extern int buf[size];
void add();
```

One clean way to read or write a global variable in C is to make functions to do it:

```
/* Csource.c: */

int get_buf(int i)
{
     if (i >= 0 && i < 5)
         return buf[i];
     else
         return 0;
}

void set_buf(int i, int value)
{
     if (i >= 0 && i < 5)
         buf[i] = value
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That way is clean.